# Swift String to date conversion found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I'm receiving a PST date inside a string in the following format `"2022-08-14 13:45:39 America/Los_Angeles"` and I'm trying to convert it to a real date using the code below which is causing the fatal error `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I'm struggling to understand how it doesn't know that this is a date given the format. The code is inside an extension block and I'm calling it like `"".stringToDate`.

```
var stringToDate: Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
        print("NEW DATE! \(date)")
        return date! // Here is where Xcode states the error is
}
```

Comment: Your format didn't include the timezone `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer does NOT solve all issues in your code. First you should set the locale before setting the dateFormat. Second you are not setting the date formatter's calendar. It will use the device's calendar which can lead to your year being interpreted with 500-2000 years offset. Note also that if your string is not well formed your parsing will fail and your app will crash. Btw the way your code is written this will create a NEW date formatter every time you call this property and that is very expensive.

Comment: @LeoDabus - The answer is correct, the locale should be irrelevant in my use case as well as the calendar as the device date isn't being used - This is being used only to convert a string to a date. The date used is from a hosted server, which I control.

Comment: Well I have already warned. It is up to you to listen or not. The locale is not irrelevant it is needed when parsing a fixed date format and again if the user device’s calendar is set to Buddhist, Chinese or Japanese  it will parse a totally different year than you expect. If you use this to parse a list it will definitely impact your app responsiveness when scrolling your table/collection view creating a new date formatter for each cell.

Comment: @LeoDabus so you're saying force .gregorian??

Comment: Yes Gregorian or ISO8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string does not include the timezone ID "America/Los_Angeles", so it fails to parse your string.

According to [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), the format pattern for parsing IDs like that is apparently `VV`.

Therefore, you should change to:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
```

and the output would be:

```
NEW DATE! Optional(2022-08-14 20:45:39 +0000)
```

which is the correct instant. 1pm in LA in the summer is 8pm UTC.

Comment: Ahhh Ok, so it needs the format of the incoming string to map it to? I thought that formatter would change it to the format you wanted.

Comment: @user72982708 Ah so that's where your misunderstanding was. Converting `String` to `Date` is called *parsing*, not *formatting*. "Formatting" is converting `Date` to `String`, and can be done by the `DateFormatter.string(from:)` method.